Scatter Plot: Value Error, Unable to Coerce to Series
I am currently working on a residual plot visualization for my perceptron. As the title states I am running into an error when calling pyplot.scatter. It seems as though the function wants n_samples to be an an array rather than 100 individual samples? If my understanding is correct, how would I go about that? If I am incorrect, what does it want from me here?
Error occurs at plt.scatter, and I assume stems from line starting with the declaration of X_new, y_new
The exact error is:
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-262bfeef3cbc> in ?()
     50     rregr.fit(X_new, y_new)
     51 
     52     preds = rregr.predict(X_new)
     53     # order is important!  actual - predictions
---> 54     plt.scatter(preds, y-preds)
     55     plt.hlines(y=0, xmin=preds.min(), xmax=preds.max())
     56     plt.show()

~/.virtualenvs/dpl-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in ?(self, other)
     72                     return NotImplemented
     73 
     74         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     75 
---> 76         return method(self, other)

~/.virtualenvs/dpl-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in ?(self, other)
    192     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__sub__")
    193     def __sub__(self, other):
--> 194         return self._arith_method(other, operator.sub)

~/.virtualenvs/dpl-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in ?(self, other, op)
   7906 
...
   8134                         msg.format(req_len=len(left.columns), given_len=len(right))
   8135                     )
   8136                 right = left._constructor_sliced(right, index=left.columns, dtype=dtype)

ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 50

code as follows:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import make_s_curve, make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path = os.path.join('../data', 'machine-data.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(path)

    ax = sns.heatmap(df.corr(numeric_only=True), annot=True)

    # histo of output
    counts = df.loc[:, 'erp'].value_counts()
    print(counts)
    sns.barplot(x=counts, y=counts.values)

    ax = sns.heatmap(df.corr(numeric_only=True).abs(), vmin= 0.65, vmax=1.0, annot=True)

    in_features = ['myct', 'mmin', 'mmax', 'cach', 'chmin', 'chmax', 'prp']
    out_features = ['erp']

    X = df.loc[:, in_features]
    y = df.loc[:, out_features]

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=123857)
    df.dropna()

    model = Perceptron()

    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print('--------------\nTraining Scores')
    print(model.score(X_train, y_train))
    print('--------------\nTesting Scores')
    print(model.score(X_test, y_test))

    X_new, y_new = make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=7)

    rregr = LinearRegression()
    rregr.fit(X_new, y_new)

    preds = rregr.predict(X_new)
    # order is important!  actual - predictions
    plt.scatter(preds, y-preds)
    plt.hlines(y=0, xmin=preds.min(), xmax=preds.max())
    plt.show()


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

maybe you have to change sizes - ie. if you have list with 100 elements then put it in another list to have list with one element which have 100 elements. This way you will have size (1, 100) instead of (100,)

just fixed the post to include the full eror. Sorry about that.
